# Enable disable and share in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-augmented-reality

i'm making an app to take a picture with an Augmented Reality object on it
I'm quite confused, can i make a single button to enable and disable at the same time? I mean, i'm using a button to show an AR object, but i can't disable it .. i already tried using boolean but still it doesn't work, the function only show enable or disable, not both, is it possible?

And i'm trying so i can share my picture on social media, i'm using twitter. But it only show my caption, my picture doesn't include, is there a way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your issue could be solved using a simple if-statement

```
if(AlreadyEnabled)
{
ARObject.setActive(false);
AlreadyEnabled = false;
}
else
{
ARObject.setActive(true);
AlreadyEnabled = true;
}
```